# Satisfying a Unary Prolog predicate

Tags: prolog

In order to write a procedure satisfy(P,L) which returns the list L of all terms X such that the unary predicate P(X) succeeds. I have attempted the following:

```
satisfy(P,L):- findall(X,call(P(X)),L).
```

Am I on the right track or I have gone completely off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using builtin predicate call/2:

```
satisfy(P, L):- findall(X, call(P, X), L).
```

Answer (score 2):

Not quite. You're on the right track using `findall/3`, but you can't construct a goal to call by simply stating `P(X)`. You need to construct the term using `=../2` instead.